# DirectX 11.1 toggle stereoscopic

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx-11, winapi

I'm fiddling with the [Direct3D stereoscopic 3D sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-111-Simple-Stereo-9b2b61aa), and was wondering if there is any way to toggle the stereoscopic view on and off while the app is running.  I'm tried manually setting `m_stereoEnabled = false`, but this still renders both left and right eye, but simply does not update the right eye rendering.  I'm fairly new to DirectX, but not software development or to 3d game development (however, my tool of choice is usually OpenGL).

It looked like I'd need to change DirectXBase::UpdateStereoEnabledStatus(), because it automatically sets m_stereoEnabled to true if my graphics card/monitor support 3d.

Answer (score -1):

I believe more information is needed about your setup for s3d. At least using XNA (which is higher level from DirectX) and Nvidia 3D Vision glasses, the stereoscopic view is rendered automatically: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/90838.aspx

Comment: You'll find all the information you need in my post and potentially in the Direct3D sample I linked to.  It's even possible to view this code without downloading it.